# Generation of SOAP Signature with multiple signed info references

Tags: security, soap, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm trying to manually create signature for my SOAP message. In a working example of that message I have two references in SignedInfo tag and two separate digests for header and body of message.

1. Given that I have multiple digests how do I get correct
   SignatureValue?
2. I have security id attributes in header    and body tags. That means
   that I have to add id's into tags and THEN    Digest this parts, am
   I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So OK, I found oscure information that after I get digest value of part i referenced in SignedInfo I need to canonicalize and digest SignedInfo element itself and only then I get my SignatureValue from that digest. UPD: Actually this info is not that obscure, just many of most googlable documents represent it wrong/not transparent enough.